# Update forge public SSH

Tags: laravel

I try to do a deploy and I get this error, I don't know if it is due to the ssh connection or the composer.lock HELP

Hello friends, I have a problem with forge, I try to do a deploy and it gives me an error that I can't solve.[image]
I'm not sure what the problem is, whether it's ssh or composer.lock, I've tried many ways but I don't know what to do anymore.
I can't log in through the console, ssh forge@137.x.x.x I try to log in and it gives me the error Permission denied (public key).

Comment: Please edit your question to [include code, data and error messages as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16563198). Your question could do with more context, for example, by forge, do you mean Minecraft Forge or something else? The error message looks like it resulted from a source control operation, so what source control solution (e.g. Git) are you using? You say this happens when deploying, but as it looks like a source control error this suggests you're using some kind of CI/CD pipeline, so more information about that would also be helpful.